# Counterexample to Rellich-Kondrachov Compactness Theorem, case $q=p^*$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, examples-counterexamples, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

I was searching some counterexample for I was searching some counterexample for Rellich-Kondrachov Compactness Theorem (You can see: PDE, Evans, chapter 5), for the case $q=p^*$ and I found this exemple in [Math over flow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81034/compact-embeddings-of-sobolev-spaces-a-counterexample-showing-the-rellich-kondr).

But I don't understood the final lines of answer proposed. For example,why

$$\varepsilon^{-\frac{n}{p^*}} u\bigg(\frac{x}{\varepsilon}\bigg)$$

is bounded in $W^{1,p}$, and why this function has a constant non-zero norm in $L^{p^∗}$, and why has no convergent subsequences there for $\varepsilon\to 0$, since it converges a.e. to zero.

Can someone a hint?
Thanks.

Comment: If you can find a counterexample, then it isn't a theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me give you a hint:

First, let us define
$$v_\epsilon:= \epsilon^{-\frac{n}{p^*}}u\left(\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right)  $$
Can you compute $\|v_\epsilon\|_{L^p}$ and $\|\nabla v_\epsilon \|_{L^p}$ in term of $u$? Try to write it down explicitly. Then you will know why it is bounded in $W^{1,p}$

Secondly, the fact that $v_\epsilon$ has no convergent subsequence in $L^{p^*}$ is because it has a constant non-zero norm in $L^{p^*}$ and $v_\epsilon\to 0$ a.e. To see why, suppose $v_\epsilon\to v$ for some $v$ in $L^{p^*}$, then we know that $\|v\|_{L^{p^*}}>0$ and hence $v$ is not 0 a.e., however, this will contradict to the fact that $v_\epsilon\to 0$ a.e.

Moreover, in this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821847686), page 324, exercise 11.15, a easier counterexample is provided. You may check it out. The idea is same but I think the calculation is easier.

Comment: I understood, thanks you so much.

Comment: (in case the link expires, the linked book is "A First Course in Sobolev Spaces (Graduate Studies in Mathematics) New ed. Edition")