# Compact embedding of $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ into $W^{k-1,p*}(\Omega)$, where $p^*$ is the Sobolev conjugate

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

How do I see that the embedding of
$$W^{k,p}(\Omega) \hookrightarrow W^{k-1,p^*}(\Omega)$$
for $1 \leq p < \infty$, the Sobolev conjugate $\frac{1}{p^*}=\frac{1}{p} - \frac{1}{n}$, and $\Omega$ open and bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a compact operator? I think the embedding is just the identity map right? But I do not see how it is a compact operator, i.e. that every bounded sequence in $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ contains a converging sequence in $W^{k-1,p^*}(\Omega)$. Does anyone know how to prove this?

Comment: Yes, it is the identity map. The compactness result is sometimes called Rellich-Kondrachoff theorem. I think it can be proved by seeing first that the operator $\Delta^{-1/2}$ is compact in $L^2(\Omega)$, which will imply that the domain of $\Delta^{1/2}$, $W^{1,2}$ embeds compactly in $L^2(\Omega)$. Then, by interpolation with the Sobolev embedding you can extend the compactness to the exponent $p^\ast$.

Answer (score 3):

The embedding is not compact. First off, you would require a Lipschitz boundare. Then we have the following [result due to Rellich and Kondrachov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rellich%E2%80%93Kondrachov_theorem).

> Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded Lipschitz domain. Further, let $m_1,m_2 \in \mathbb{N}_0$ and $p_1,p_2 \in [1,\infty)$. If
>   $$m_1 - \frac{n}{p_1}>m_2-\frac{n}{p_2} \quad \text{and} \quad m_1>m_2,$$
>   then $W^{m_1,p_1}(\Omega)$ is continuously, compactly embedded in $W^{m_2,p_2}(\Omega)$ via the identity mapping.

In your case we take $m_1=k, m_2=k-1, p_1=p, p_2=p^*$. Then we have 
$$k-\frac{n}{p}>k-1-\frac{n}{p*} \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{n}>\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{p^*}.$$
But by assumption you have an equality there and because of that compactness of the embedding it not true (but the continuity still holds). See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81034/compact-embeddings-of-sobolev-spaces-a-counterexample-showing-the-rellich-kondr) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1326250/counterexample-to-rellich-kondrachov-compactness-theorem-case-q-p) for an counter-example in the case $k=1,p=2$ that Rellich's theorem is indeed sharp.

Sometimes one also sees the version of Rellich's theorem that $W^{m_1,p_1}$ is compactly embedded in $W^{m_2,p_2}$ if $p_1 \in [1,n)$ and $p_2 \in [1,\frac{np}{n-p}]$. So as before, we notice that the Sobolev conjugate is excluded.